# Differentiation inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, solution-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function for which $|f(y)-f(x)|\leq |y^3-x^3|$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $|f'(x)|\leq 3x^2$.

Attempt: I have proved that $f'(0)=0$ by use of the difference quotient. Now differentiate term by term: $|f'(y)-f'(x)|\leq |3y^2{'}-3x^2|$. Since $f'(y)=0$, we have $f'(x)\leq 3x^2$.

However, I also know that $f'(x)<g'(x)\nRightarrow f(x)<g(x)$ and vice-versa, so how am I actually supposed to prove the claim? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't suppose $f$ differentiable (if it's not, your statement is wrong). Suppose it is. Then,$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x^3-y^3|\implies \left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\leq |x^2+yx+y^2|.$$

Taking $x\to y$ gives the wished result.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{gather*}
|f( y) -f( x) |\leqslant |y^{3} -x^{3} |\\
|f( x+h) -f( x) |\leqslant |( x+h)^{3} -x^{3} |\\
|f( x+h) -f( x) |\leqslant |h\left( x^{2} +h^{2} +2xh+x^{2} +x^{2} +xh\right) |\\
|f( x+h) -f( x) |\leqslant |h\left( 3x^{2} +3xh+h^{2}\right) |
\end{gather*}
Can you now use the definition of derivatives to finish it off now?